# How to show significance stars in R Markdown (rmarkdown) html output notes?

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer, texreg

I want to show regression outputs in HTML documents using R Markdown. I tried the `texreg` and `stargazer`packages. My problem is now, that in the notes I can't bring the significance stars to life. Due to automatic generation it seems I can't escape them. I've been puzzling around with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460359/r-markdown-htmltabular-outputting-escape-characters-breaking-tables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033724/issue-creating-model-summary-table-using-package-texreg-with-rstudio-rmarkdown-k) but with no success. What am I missing? Thanks a lot!!

Here's some code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r data}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
```
## with STARGAZER
```{r table1, results = "asis", message=FALSE}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(lm1, type="html", notes="stargazer html 1") # nothing
stargazer(lm1, type="html", notes="stargazer html 2", star.char = "\\*") # nothing, even gone in table
```
## with TEXREG
```{r table2, results = "asis", message=FALSE}
library(texreg)
htmlreg(lm1, custom.note="%stars. htmlreg") # nothing
htmlreg(lm1, custom.note="%stars. htmlreg", star.symbol = "\\*") # still nothing!
```
````

*Note:* Question was a former [sub-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457243/regression-tables-in-r-markdown-html-pdf) I have now splitted.

Comment: Have you tried `star.symbol='&#42;'`?

Comment: That works fantastic with `texreg/htmlreg` thanks!! In `stargazer` no changes, but even not when setting `star.char = 'x'`. My conclusion is to use the former for html and the latter for latex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the HTML entity for the asterisk:

```
star.symbol='&#42;'
```

See http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

You could also add the "legend" manually:

```
stargazer(lm1, type="html", notes = "<em>&#42;p&lt;0.1;&#42;&#42;p&lt;0.05;&#42;&#42;&#42;p&lt;0.01</em>", notes.append = F)
```

[image]